# How can I make a group of blurry colors in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient

I have downloaded an asset that shows as the picture attached. [image: Blurry colors]

The image is slightly warped with the warp tool (U) (may not be the correct translation as English is not my main language).

I wonder how could be this done, as I'm double clicking it but I'm unable to get deeper in layers. Is it an imported picture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [4 colors/corners gradient with Illustrator or Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/4-colors-corners-gradient-with-illustrator-or-photoshop) -- Although this refers to corner variations, the same method can be used for *any* subtle blended gradients.. i.e. **Gradient Mesh** in Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott this will be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest versions of Illustrator, a option has been added to gradients. It allows you to color an area from points. You can add as many as you want, apparently. You give each one a color and move them around, giving the size of each one.

If you want to use this option, it is located in the gradient panel, the third type, being the first one lineal gradient, the second radial gradient, and the third one the one that will allow you to create a picture very close to this one.

Comment: The gradient mesh?

Comment: I don't know what the name in English is, as my program is in Spanish, but it looks like so.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an image and you want the effect like that. If you don't have image, you just want that look, following method might work for you.

You can use *Filter > Blur > Guassian Blur* to any image, if you have Photoshop.

Or *Effect > Blur > Guassian Blur* in Illustrator.

For example, I applied it on Pepsi's Logo:

[image]

You can apply it to any image, depending on which colors you want in your output.

Also, it seems a raster effect. I would personally do it in Photoshop instead of Illustrator.

Comment: He/She's asking about Illustrator though.

Comment: @Scott oh. I've edited it. Is it better?

Comment: No, this is not what I'm asking, I mean, the colors should be vectors after all. I've found a tool though. I don't know if that was done with it but I will post my own answer.

Comment: Good. You didn't mention you need vector. So I didn't I think you need something like this.